# Screen Sharing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, screen-sharing

Is it possible on the iPhone to share the screen live? In other words I would have an app on the iPhone that would allow a person to see my screen live while they watched via a secure URL.

I have seen some apps that allow for screen sharing of files from the iPhone but not the actual screen.

If it is not possible to share the screen live is it possible to record a video of the screen?

Notes: I am not looking for ways to control another iPhone just show the screen live, I am *not* on a jailbroken iPhone, and I am running iOS 6. Also I am curious to the same for the iPad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I AirPlay mirror my iPhone screen to my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139989/how-do-i-airplay-mirror-my-iphone-screen-to-my-macbook-pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're looking for a solution to "stream" your iPhone screen directly to the Internet, the answer is NO.

But if you are willing to break the problem down to two, that might be possible with an external computer, PC or Mac, though PC is recommended.

Two break it into two parts, you first want your iPhone screen to appear on the Mac or PC's screen. We'll use something called "Airplay Mirroring", and on Mac and PC, "Air Server", or an app on Mac "Reflector". You can find both Air Server and Reflector on the Internet, and both offers trial.

Then you want to stream your Mac or PC's screen to the Internet. On Mac, I DON'T prefer any application, they are all slow and have poor quality. This is what I like, "[321ShowIt](http://www.321showit.com)", which is Java-based, but works better than the solutions [here](http://www.justin.tv/p/mac_broadcasting).

There's also a down side to 321ShowIt, it streams to a webpage that needs Java to watch. But those other solutions streams to Twitch, where people need only Flash, and have dedicated apps on both iOS and Android.

On PC, you of course can use 321ShowIt, but I prefer [XSplit Broadcaster](http://www.xsplit.com), it's an amazing high quality streaming application for a wide range of platform, including Justin.tv and so on.

So, if those don't suit your need, a jailbreak will be required. But even so, you will be limited to providing VNC connection. Streaming from iOS device is really not a good option since compressing the H.264 stream and serving it live will cause a noticeable performance hit on even the fastest Apple A6.

Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For recording the screen as a video, this site seems to sum up the ways nicely:

http://www.apptamin.com/blog/capture-iphone-ipad-screen-video/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out..
http://mgalligan.com/post/29978268510/screen-share-iphone-live-on-internet

Hope it Helps...

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.