# How do I AirPlay mirror my iPhone screen to my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, ios, airplay

I am using a 13 inch Retina MacBook Pro with Mavericks and a iPhone 5s with iOS 7.

I want to record game tutorials. Where the game is running on my iOS device and I'm recording the tutorial via a screen capture of an AirPlay on my MacBook Pro.

After searching apps from the App Store, I found that there is no apps to record your screen and the only way is through AirPlay on your Mac or Apple TV.

Is there any **free** and legal way to do do?

I have tried a trial of X mirage and it is just what I wanted, but it cost money. I want to record my iPhone.

Note that I do not have any other apple devices.

Comment: Maybe you want to include in your question, which device you want to record and why you would need the second. And after a quick Google Search, I couldn't find 'X marige', typo?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question to provide further information.

Comment: Does it have to be **free**?

Comment: Yes, it should be free. I know a few paid ones

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If your devices have OS X Yosemite and iOS 8 or anything newer, [there's a built-in way to do this via a wired connection.](http://www.labnol.org/software/quicktime-ios-screen-recorder/8375/)

1. Quit QuickTime on your Mac if it is open.
2. Connect your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch to your Mac via a Lightning or USB-C Cable.
3. Open QuickTime on your Mac, and select **File** > **New Movie Recording**.
4. A recording window will appear. Click the arrow next to the Record button, and select your iPhone from the dropdown menu that appears.
5. Click the Record button and go about your business on your iPhone.
6. Once you're done, click the Stop button and save the video.

Comment: URL is broken.but I got the idea of use QuickTime for recording.

Comment: @RafaelGorski Thanks for pointing it out! I just changed it to a link that looks pretty non-broken.

Comment: If all you want to do is play, I found you can skip steps 4 and 5. Thanks so much for pointing out this great feature of Quicktime "Player".  :)

Comment: Just keep in mind it doesnt work if you are in a phone call :(

Comment: It also interrupts any Xcode debugging sessions.

Comment: Its not workiing for Hotstar and amazon prime videos.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra That makes sense, apps can probably avoid being recorded, similar to how Mac screen recordings won't show iTunes video.

Comment: @user24601 so, is there anyway to add those app videos, its not working on youtube either ..!

Answer (score 8):

An app which works great for me is [Reflector.](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) Its not free, but there is an unrestricted 7-day trial for you to experiment with. You can use the free [Quicktime Player](http://www.cultofmac.com/245619/record-your-macs-screen-for-free-with-quicktime-player-os-x-tips/) on your Mac to record a video of the screen (or a selected portion thereof) of the iDevice, once Reflector is displaying it on the screen.

I use this combination all the time.

Comment: Yes, it should be free. I know a few paid ones –  J_W 3 hours ago

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Find a answer with Free to use not free to download, and explain how to use GT on iPhone to record screen capture video+sound and you get plus points from me.

Comment: I've added more precise information about how to use Quicktime Player on the Mac to capture the iDevice output into video. We've been trying to find a free app, but we've had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as others have suggested and download another piece of (paid) software for your Mac, or simply hang tight until iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite come out, at which point (assuming Apple maintains the feature) the QuickTime Screen Recording function will work on an iOS 8 device connected to the computer via USB. 
In addition, a service called [iRec](https://twitter.com/iRecApp) should allow you to do what you want (without the use of a computer) once it is released later this year.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and install iTools Pro on your Mac.
2. Connect your Mac and iPhone to same network.
3. Click on Airplayer button from iTools's windows.
4. Wait for Airplayer to be downloaded.
5. Connect to Airplayer through Airplay from your iPhone. Enjoy!!

[image]

Comment: Please see the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and make sure you disclose if you are affiliated with a product.

Comment: I'm not doing promotion or I'm not affiliated with that company. And I'm not giving any affiliated link to the website. This is the answer what they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to Airserver, which is an app that turns your Mac into an Airplay receiver.
See airserver.com
It is not free, but for $15 you can solve the problem.
I use it all the time to either display my iPad or iPhone on a beamer connected to my Mac and use screen recording software to record tutorials.

Comment: Works for me and it's cheap (relatively)!

Answer (score 1):

You can screen capture the iPhone directly using QuickTime on the MacBook and connect the iPhone via USB cable to the MacBook. Here is the link to a tutorial:
http://www.labnol.org/software/quicktime-ios-screen-recorder/8375/

This way you don't need reflector and the quality is even better.

Comment: But apple should make this available over the air.

Answer (score 1):

Use QuickTime Player (which is pre-installed on OS X)

Answer (score -4):

Use Shou screen recorder, no need jailbreak, download from https://shou.tv/ios